# Source Code Mapping/Crawling Application for TypeScript and C#

Tags: c#, mapping, flowchart, typescript

This is my first time asking a question here.  I have been looking for a particular software development tool, but I cannot find what I am looking for.

I need an application that can build an interactive map for a web-application's Angular/TypeScript/.NET code base. I want something that can trace a particular URI (e.g. /product/1234) all the way through the client-side Angular code files and method calls.

It should:

- Start with the application's entry point (e.g. main.ts)
- Navigate the routing logic and point the user to the page's main TypeScript and HTML snippets
- Trace the route through which the desired data is retrieved (e.g. the details about product #1234)
- This route description chain includes every file/class/method called between the page's main TypeScript/HTML and the API call back to the server (or client-side data store)
- For all child Angular tags used in the page, this process repeats, mapping each one's chain of object method calls to the API request/data store

In a perfect world, it would also:

- Continue tracing with the API endpoints' entry files/classes/methods
- Trace the API endpoint's activity through all the business logic and down to the data store

In day-to-day use, a user can run the application and give it a URI (e.g. product/1234), and the relevant portion of our application's chart will be displayed.

I have already played with and rejected Visual Studio's Code Map.  It cannot handle the Angular TypeScript and HTML.  It's use tracking the server side API logic leaves much to be desired.

Comment: You could improve the post by using bullets for your requirements, and by removing the waffle and musings.